# When registering a table using the %pyspark interpreter in Zeppelin, I can't access the table in %sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin 0.5.5. I found this code/sample here for python as I couldn't get my own to work with %pyspark http://www.makedatauseful.com/python-spark-sql-zeppelin-tutorial/. I have a feeling his %pyspark example worked because if you using the original %spark zeppelin tutorial the "bank" table is already created.

This code is in a notebook.

```
%pyspark
from os import getcwd
# sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) # Removed with latest version I tested
zeppelinHome = getcwd()
bankText = sc.textFile(zeppelinHome+"/data/bank-full.csv")

bankSchema = StructType([StructField("age", IntegerType(),     False),StructField("job", StringType(), False),StructField("marital", StringType(), False),StructField("education", StringType(), False),StructField("balance", IntegerType(), False)])

bank = bankText.map(lambda s: s.split(";")).filter(lambda s: s[0] != "\"age\"").map(lambda s:(int(s[0]), str(s[1]).replace("\"", ""), str(s[2]).replace("\"", ""), str(s[3]).replace("\"", ""), int(s[5]) ))

bankdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(bank,bankSchema)
bankdf.registerAsTable("bank")
```

This code is in the same notebook but different work pad.

```
%sql 
SELECT count(1) FROM bank

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table bank; line 1 pos 21
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem to this issue. Prior to 0.6.0 the sqlContext variable is sqlc in %pyspark.

Defect can be found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-134

> In Pyspark, the SQLContext is currently available in the variable name sqlc. This is incosistent with the documentation and with the variable name in scala which is sqlContext.
>
> sqlContext can be used as a variable for the SQLContext, in addition to sqlc (for backward compatibility)
>
> Related code:
> https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/resources/python/zeppelin_pyspark.py#L66

The suggested workaround is simply to do the following in your %pyspark script

sqlContext = sqlc

Found here:

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-zeppelin-users/201506.mbox/%3CCALf24sazkTxVd3EpLKTWo7yfE4NvW032j346N+6AuB7KKZS_AQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sqlContext, use sqlc and replace registerAsTable by sqlc.registerDataFrameAsTable

```
%pyspark
from os import getcwd
zeppelinHome = getcwd()
bankText = sc.textFile(zeppelinHome+"/data/bank-full.csv")

bankSchema = StructType([StructField("age", IntegerType(), False),StructField("job", StringType(), False),StructField("marital", StringType(), False),StructField("education", StringType(), False),StructField("balance", IntegerType(), False)])

bank = bankText.map(lambda s: s.split(";")).filter(lambda s: s[0] != "\"age\"").map(lambda s:(int(s[0]), str(s[1]).replace("\"", ""), str(s[2]).replace("\"", ""), str(s[3]).replace("\"", ""), int(s[5]) ))

bankdf = sqlc.createDataFrame(bank,bankSchema)
sqlc.registerDataFrameAsTable(bankdf, "bank")


%sql 
SELECT count(1) FROM bank
```