# Zeppelin - Cannot query with %sql a table I registered with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am new to spark/zeppelin and I wanted to complete a simple exercise, where I will transform a csv file from pandas to Spark data frame and then register the table to query it with sql and visualise it using Zeppelin.

But I seem to be failing in the last step.

I am using Spark 1.6.1

Here is my code:

```
%pyspark
spark_clean_df.registerTempTable("table1")
print spark_clean_df.dtypes
print sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from table1").collect()
```

Here is the output:

```
[('id', 'bigint'), ('name', 'string'), ('host_id', 'bigint'), ('host_name', 'string'), ('neighbourhood', 'string'), ('latitude', 'double'), ('longitude', 'double'), ('room_type', 'string'), ('price', 'bigint'), ('minimum_nights', 'bigint'), ('number_of_reviews', 'bigint'), ('last_review', 'string'), ('reviews_per_month', 'double'), ('calculated_host_listings_count', 'bigint'), ('availability_365', 'bigint')]
[Row(_c0=4961)]
```

But when I try to use %sql I get this error:

```
%sql
select * from table1

Table not found: table1; line 1 pos 14
set zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace = true to see full stacktrace
```

Any help would be appreciated - I don't even know where to find this stacktrace and how could it help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: This link was particularly useful when dealing with this issue: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 4):

Zeppelin can create different contexts for different interpreters it is possible that if you executed some code with %spark and some code with %pyspark interpreters your Zeppelin can have two contexts. And when you use %sql it is looking in another context not in %pyspark.
Try restart Zeppelin and execute %pyspark code as first statement and than %sql as second.

If you go to 'Interpreters' tab you can add zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace there. And after restart Zeppelin you will see full stack trace in a place where you have 'Table not found' now.

Actually this is probably answer to your question 
[When registering a table using the %pyspark interpreter in Zeppelin, I can't access the table in %sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882360/when-registering-a-table-using-the-pyspark-interpreter-in-zeppelin-i-cant-acc)

Try to do

```
    %pyspark
    sqlContext = sqlc
```

as first two lines

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion, but I think it is not what I was looking for. I have further tested what could be the problem and came up with this solution: I need to create a schema of the new table first, create an empty table based on the schema and parse the data frame column by column and the pass these values from data.frame to sql table before I register it. Otherwise what I register is empty nothing. Quite annoying and not very friendly to use... What I found easier is visualise the data with matplotlib and not register the table as sql to query it and use Zeppelins visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

also related to the **different contexts created by spark** check the following setting in the spark interpreter

```
zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext = false
```

set the setting to 'false'

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which interpreter group you were using. If it's `livy` then you can't access tables registered in `%livy.pyspark` from `%livy.sql`. I got this from [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/70235/getting-table-not-found-exception-in-sql-interpret.html):

```
for now %livy.sql can only access tables registered %livy.spark, but not %livy.pyspark and %livy.sparkr.
```

If you switch to the standard `spark` interpreter group it should work. I can confirm this for me using Spark 1.6.3 and Zeppelin 0.7.0. Hopefully the people working on the livy interpreter will fix this restriction...

Comment: As far as I know, there was no %livy.pyspark interpreter. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the machine anymore, so I cannot tell for sure. Thanks for the tip and link anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax would be:

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(spark_clean_df, 'table1')
sqlContext.sql(select * from table1 where ...)
```